# Get specific output from HTML

Tags: php, html, dom, find

```
<div class="info">
    <ul class="links">
    </ul>
    <h1>Vykúpenie z väznice Shawshank</h1>
    <ul class="names">
       <li>
       <img src="http://img.csfd.cz/assets/images/flags/flag_1.gif" alt="USA"  />
       <h3>Shawshank Redemption, The</h3>
       </li>
       <li>
       <img src="http://img.csfd.cz/assets/images/flags/flag_34.gif" alt="CZ název"  />
       <h3>Vykoupení z věznice Shawshank</h3>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Hey guys, this is part of big HTML, what i need is to use HTML SIMPLE DOM PRASER and get this 3 text : "Vyykúpenie z väznice Shawshank", "Shawshank Redemption, The", "Vykoupení z věznice Shawshank" How should i do that?

my try of PHP code:

```
$html = file_get_html('file.txt'); 
$ret = $html->find('ul[class="links"]');   //nazov filmu


foreach ($ret as $translate) {
    $translate = $translate->innertext;
    }   
    echo "$translate";
```

Comment: is u need to get content in h3 tag..

Comment: Where is `<a href="">`? what do you want to do? it's not clear. can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do the translation. You can use contants you can use method. The one of my favourite way is to use **[Zend Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.introduction.html)** check it.

The main aim is to create method which will change some contants depending on language.

```
 class Translator
 {
    public static $lang = 'en';
    public function translate($str){
       if(isset($this->data[$str]))
       return $this->data[$str];
       else return 'no translation';
    }
 }

 $translate->('DO_HOMEWORK');
```

Language should be stored in session and depends on language it should give proper values. You can get `$this->data` from **CSV** files, **ini** files or get it straightly from the array it doesn't really mater. You can use singleton pattern to Translator class.

Comment: Nope mate i have data translated , what i need to get them FROM my HTML file :)

Comment: use simple html parser `http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/` and `file_get_html()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want so:

```
<div class="info">
    <ul class="links">
        <li><h1>Vykúpenie z väznice Shawshank</h1>
            <ul class="names">
                <li>
                    <img src="http://img.csfd.cz/assets/images/flags/flag_1.gif" alt="USA"  />
                    <h3>Shawshank Redemption, The</h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://img.csfd.cz/assets/images/flags/flag_34.gif" alt="CZ název"  />
                    <h3>Vykoupení z věznice Shawshank</h3>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```